# Generating SQL Tables from XML Altova XMLSPY

Tags: xml, t-sql, altova, xmlschemaset

I have an XML file from my old CRM and I am ultimately importing this in Salesforce.

I feel good having it in SQL Server first. The problem is, I'm not great with XML and recalling TSQL with XML is rather tedious. I also recall that Altova has some nice tools to handle and view XML files.

With XML sply I see a great feature to suggest in import the XML to SQL Server. I'd really like this.

Here are the errors I get using Altova.

I wonder if there is a simple citation I can make on my XML file to make this work? In one case I've generated an XML schema. In the other I'm trying to cite the XML WSDL which is required for the XMLSPY's export to database feature.

Can someone guide me on the big picture? How close am I to using Altova to suggest the SQL structure? I'll post this and get started on the TSQL only solution, certain I can make that work in a few hours. But I'd like to know if Altova can do this easily and what I can learn about streamlining XML to SQL with that tool.

[Altova XML SPY complaint about Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/173cs.png)

[Altova XMLSPY complaint about XSDL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94kj5.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions with many spelling errors make it very unclear, so this question will be liable to closure.

Comment: Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57717239/getting-xml-to-feed-into-sql-server-table